# Redistribute connected/static interfaces into ospf?

Tags: bgp, ospf

If you are running eBGP with several transit providers, what is best practice for redistributing into ospf?  Would we want to redistribute the connected/static subnets into ospf?

If yes, what is the benefit of doing that?

If not, what is the reason for not doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be a bit more precise in what you want to do. Do you want to redistribute eBGP into OSPF (bad idea) or only connected/static networks? If not, please remove the eBGP sentence as it has no relevance to redistribution of static/connected routes into OSPF.

Comment: There is no "best practice."  How you end up configuring your routing depends on a lot of factors.  For example,  when you say transit providers, does that mean you are providing transit as well?  If so, what is your routing policy? How many BGP routers do you have?  One for each provider, or are some combined?  What does your internal topology look like?

Comment: @Sebastian, I've been reading that ospf should only be enabled on the transit interfaces and then you redistribute the connected/static into ospf.  When I say transit providers, we get transit from major carriers such as Tinet, Telia, etc so we are multihomed. We have 2 edge routers, 2 core routers, and multiple distribution switches under the cores.

Comment: Whenever possible prefer ospf network statements to redistribution.   Redistribution into OSPF results in additional Type4 LSAs for every ASBR.  Type4 LSAs cannot be processed in an [incremental spf](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/ospfispf.html) run, and generally increase the work OSPF must do.  Redistribute connected develops bad OSPF configuration habits that I've built a fair portion of my career untangling in various networks.

Comment: @NetworkNinja Oh sorry I think I misunderstood your question. You're asking if you should redistribute the transit interfaces to the eBGP peers into OSPF, right?

Comment: If you are injecting a default route(s) from your edge routers, you may not need to include the transit networks at all.  How are you routing to your two providers?  Are you prefering one provider over the other, or are you redistributing some BGP into OSPF to make a choice based on destination?   Everything @MikePennington says is true, but only for multiple areas.  With only four routers, I'm assuming a single area, and therefore no type-4 LSAs.

Comment: @Ron, it's unwise to build configurations that rely on no OSPF area changes; it's easier just to build it so it will scale correctly... in fact, some of the cluster-forks I mentioned in my last comment developed as a result of just this assumption (our network is small, so redistribute connected is ok)

Comment: @MikePennington if everyone built networks correctly, we'd be out of a job ;-).  My main point was the specific problem you mentioned only occurs in large multi-area networks.

Comment: @Ron, my main point was that you should always prefer native OSPF network statements.  Everything you said after that is either superfluous or confusing the issue, if you agree with my original statement.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys.  Has been helpful so far.  Like the discussion a lot Ron and Mike :)

Comment: So @NetworkNinja, are you injecting a default route from your edge?  If so, how do you choose each one?

Comment: Right now, we aren't preferring one provider over another or manipulating traffic by any other means.  It's all "equal" so to speak btw the transit providers. Right now, we just have redistribute connected & static under the ospf process.  You are correcti nthat it's a single area 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Adding BGP next-hops to OSPF

Promoting my comments to an answer...

> If you are running eBGP with several transit providers, what is best practice for redistributing into ospf? Would we want to redistribute the connected/static subnets into ospf?

You should only redistribute your routes to connected BGP next-hops into OSPF as a last resort.   Whenever you redistribute routes in OSPF:

- You're [requiring yet another Type4 LSA for every OSPF ASBR](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/redistribute-connected-static-interfaces-into-ospf#comment11493_7021) (if you're in a multiple-OSPF-area scenario)
- You're [building bad OSPF configuration habits](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/redistribute-connected-static-interfaces-into-ospf#comment11498_7021)

One of OSPF's scaling points is based on the number of LSAs carried in the AS ([especially external LSAs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/7039-1.html#t34a)).  You should generally try to avoid unnecessary LSA generation, because these additional LSAs incrementally slow down convergence during topology changes, due to flooding requirements.

Furthermore, since `redistribute connected` creates OSPF external routes; these external routes can only be summarized at the originating [OSPF ASBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First#Autonomous_system_boundary_router) or [NSSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First#Not-so-stubby_area) ABR.  External routes limit your ability to aggregate address space (and laying out address space such that you can [summarize](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/7039-1.html#t29) at [OSPF ABR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First#Area_border_router)s is a key principle of good IGP/OSPF design).

In short: always prefer internal OSPF routes, if possible.  There are valid use-cases for external routes, but needlessly spamming OSPF E1 or E2 routes throughout the AS with `redistribute connected` could eventually cause you more pain than necessary... sometimes a lot of pain.

### eBGP Next-Hop resolution

One of BGP's decision points is whether the eBGP next-hop is reachable for a prefix.  If the eBGP next-hop is not reachable (perhaps you didn't include it in your OSPF table), then the route is rejected as a candidate best-path.

There are a few ways that you can ensure that the eBGP next-hop always resolves... I'm listing them in order or preference.

1. When using direct BGP peering, ensure your [BGP peering interfaces are included in your IGP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/redistribute-connected-static-interfaces-into-ospf#comment11493_7021) (in this case, OSPF)
2. When using indirect (i.e. [eBGP multi-hop](http://wiki.nil.com/EBGP_load_balancing_with_EBGP_session_between_loopback_interfaces)), redistribute your static routes to the BGP peer's next-hop.
3. Use [`next-hop self`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/iproute_bgp/command/reference/irg_book/irg_bgp3.html#wp1108213) on iBGP sessions (which generally means you won't need to worry about next-hop resolution, but comes at the expense of knowing IGP costs to the next-hop)
4. Use a default route, as was [suggested above](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/redistribute-connected-static-interfaces-into-ospf#comment11496_7021)

The key take-away is that your BGP route will be rejected if the [eBGP next-hop IP address does not resolve through an IGP route](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13753-25.html#background) (ref: *Paths for which the NEXT_HOP is inaccessible*).

Even so, the four options listed above are not equal, because BGP also considers the [IGP cost to the next-hop](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13753-25.html#bestpath) as a path discriminator.  If one relies on a default route to resolve next-hops, you have:

- Removed this as a decision point, making your BGP path selection less accurate (by default)
- Made eBGP outbound load-distribution less granular (in other words, you wind up sending all BGP traffic through the default, unless you have an explicit next-hop in the IGP)
- Created a potential black-hole if the default route doesn't cover all possible next-hop routers.

The aforementioned disadvantages go away if you simply add your BGP next-hop interfaces into OSPF.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer.  Also sent you an email :)  Please check when you have a  minute.

Comment: Another slam-dunk answer.